# Spring Cloud Config Not Supported in Spring boot > 3.1.0-M1?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to create a spring boot project with spring cloud config as the dependency. I am selecting spring boot version 3.1.0 (M1). However, I cannot select the Config Server as it shown greyed out with the message that the required version is >=2.3.0.M1 and <3.1.0-M1. I wonder is there something else we need to use if we are going for spring boot version > 3.1.0-M1. I have attached the screenshot here.

[image]

I tried googling the info above but did not find anything relevant to that.

Comment: What Java version do you have?

Comment: I have Java 17.

Comment: There are snapshots that work. And there will be a release of 2022.0 in the future that will be compatible

Comment: however, why they are not supported as of now? do they have plan to move away from the spring cloud config? Anything better may be?

Comment: Does it work when importing it manually in your `pom.xml` instead defined at Spring Initializr?

Comment: The snapshots work. We've been testing for weeks. It's just not on initializr